# how to get location of facebook user using Graph API for android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am able to get name,email,gender and birth date using the following code

loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends,user_location")); //I also added user_location

```
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                        }
                    });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,location");   //and location parameter
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Log.v("LoginActivity", "cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
        }
    });
```

but it only returns the following values.

```
07-22 12:53:05.639: E/Fb data(6560): {"id":"989472891104","name":"Karan Mer","email":"karan_mer2012@yahoo.co.in","gender":"male"}
```

how can I get that???

Comment: did you get any solution, even i want to access the users location

Answer (score 1):

Without submitting the app for review on facebook we are not able to get location of facebook user. But for testing purpose you can get the location of App Developer, Admin or Tester.

Download the source code from here ([Get location of facebook user using Graph API in android](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2017/04/07/get-location-of-facebook-user-using-graph-api-in-android/))

Add this dependency:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"

            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
        android:text="Email"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_email"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="DOB"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
            android:text="DOB"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_dob"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_email"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Location"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
            android:text="location"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_location"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#6585C8"
        android:id="@+id/ll_facebook"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook"
            android:id="@+id/iv_facebook"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login with Facebook"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/tv_facebook"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package facebooklocation.facebooklocation;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    ImageView iv_image, iv_facebook;
    TextView tv_name, tv_email, tv_dob, tv_location, tv_facebook;
    LinearLayout ll_facebook;
    String str_facebookname, str_facebookemail, str_facebookid, str_birthday, str_location;
    boolean boolean_login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
        getKeyHash();
        listener();
    }


    private void init() {
        iv_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
        iv_facebook = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_facebook);
        tv_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        tv_dob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_dob);
        tv_location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
        tv_facebook = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_facebook);
        ll_facebook = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_facebook);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    }

    private void listener() {
        tv_facebook.setOnClickListener(this);
        ll_facebook.setOnClickListener(this);
        iv_facebook.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void facebookLogin() {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.e("ONSUCCESS", "User ID: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                        + "\n" + "Auth Token: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                );
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                try {

                                    boolean_login = true;
                                    tv_facebook.setText("Logout from Facebook");

                                    Log.e("object", object.toString());
                                    str_facebookname = object.getString("name");

                                    try {
                                        str_facebookemail = object.getString("email");
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        str_facebookemail = "";
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    try {
                                        str_facebookid = object.getString("id");
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        str_facebookid = "";
                                        e.printStackTrace();

                                    }


                                    try {
                                        str_birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        str_birthday = "";
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jsonobject_location = object.getJSONObject("location");
                                        str_location = jsonobject_location.getString("name");

                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        str_location = "";
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    fn_profilepic();

                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                }
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, email,gender,birthday,location");

                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
                    return; // already logged out
                }
                new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest
                        .Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,email"));
                        facebookLogin();

                    }
                }).executeAsync();


            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.e("ON ERROR", "Login attempt failed.");


                AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,email,user_birthday"));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        try {
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    private void getKeyHash() {
        // Add code to print out the key hash
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("facebooklocation.facebooklocation", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
    }

    private void fn_profilepic() {

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putBoolean("redirect", false);
        params.putString("type", "large");
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "me/picture",
                params,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                        Log.e("Response 2", response + "");

                        try {
                            String str_facebookimage = (String) response.getJSONObject().getJSONObject("data").get("url");
                            Log.e("Picture", str_facebookimage);

                            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(str_facebookimage).skipMemoryCache(true).into(iv_image);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        tv_name.setText(str_facebookname);
                        tv_email.setText(str_facebookemail);
                        tv_dob.setText(str_birthday);
                        tv_location.setText(str_location);

                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (boolean_login) {
            boolean_login = false;
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            tv_location.setText("");
            tv_dob.setText("");
            tv_email.setText("");
            tv_name.setText("");
            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.profile).into(iv_image);
            tv_facebook.setText("Login with Facebook");
        } else {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,email,user_birthday,user_location"));
            facebookLogin();
        }


    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   private void facebookLogin() {
        callbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
                getProfileDetail(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.e("CANCEL : ","CANCEL");
                // App code

                if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
                    return; // already logged out
                }
                new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest
                        .Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(FacebookActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,email"));
                        facebookLogin();

                    }
                }).executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
                AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(FacebookActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,email,user_birthday"));
                Log.e("ERROR : ",exception.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void getProfileDetail(AccessToken accessToken) {
        GraphRequest graphRequest=GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                String name = null;
                String email = null;
                String profileImage_link = null;
                String user_id = null;
                 String location = null;
                try {
                if (object.has("name"))
                {
                        name=object.getString("name");
                }

                if (object.has("email"))
                {
                    email=object.getString("email");
                }

                if (object.has("id"))
                {
                    user_id=object.getString("id");
                }

                profileImage_link=object.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                    Log.e("PICTURE URL : ",profileImage_link);

                    Log.e("Detail : ","Name : "+name+ "   Email : "+email+ "   User_id : "+user_id+"  Location : "+location);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.e("Object : ",object.toString());
                tv_response.setText(object.toString());
                String str_birthday =null;
                String str_location=null;
                try {
                    str_birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    str_birthday = "";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonobject_location = object.getJSONObject("location");
                    str_location = jsonobject_location.getString("name");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    str_location = "";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.e("LOCATION : ",str_location+"   "+str_birthday);
            }


        });

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(
                "fields",
                "id,name,link,email,gender,picture.type(large),last_name,first_name,locale,timezone,updated_time,verified,birthday,location"
        );
        graphRequest.setParameters(bundle);
        graphRequest.executeAsync();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to provide user_location for that

then in your

```
public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response){

    JSONObject jsonObj = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
    GraphUser user = GraphObject.Factory.create(jsonObj,GraphUser.class);
    if (user.getLocation() != null && getLocation().getProperty("name")!= null) {
        userObject.userCity = user.getLocation().getProperty("name").toString();
    }
}
```

this worked for me, hope this works for you

Note: You may have to do, the facebook review, for getting users location.

Comment: What is GraphUser class?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/interface/GraphUser/

it is a part of facebook sdk v3.0,... now it may have got deprecated