# How to get user email and birthday from Facebook API Version v2.4

Tags: android, facebook

I am not able to get the facebook user email in API version v2.4. I have one app in api version2.3 it returns the email and other details of the user but now facebook updated the api version to new application. if i use the old application like veriosn <=2.3 its returning the user email by using the following code. But in api version 2.4 i am not able to get the email and date of birth.

```
GraphRequest.newMeRequest(result.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject me, GraphResponse response)
        {
            if (response.getError() != null)
            {
                // handle error
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("",""+me.toString());
                Log.e("",""+response.getJSONObject().toString());

            }
        }
    }).executeAsync();
```

Comment: check this out I am able to get email and birthday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909137/how-to-get-location-of-facebook-user-using-graph-api-for-android

Comment: @Karan Mer, this one is working for the app which created in Facebook api v2.3 or less than that. now in api v2.4 its returning only id and name.

Comment: then use latest facebook sdk

Comment: @Karan Mer, thanks, passing permission with graph api as well as with login button is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to explicitly define which fields you want to retrieve with your request, for example `/me?fields=id,name,email,birthday` instead of just `/me`

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

> To try to improve performance on mobile networks, Nodes and Edges in v2.4 requires that you explicitly request the field(s) you need for your GET requests. For example, GET /v2.4/me/feed no longer includes likes and comments by default, but GET /v2.4/me/feed?fields=comments,likes will return the data. For more details see the docs on how to request specific fields.

Comment: i have set the permissions with login button like this, mLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email", "user_birthday"));

Comment: Maybe, but you need to specify the fields in the actual Graph API request. I can't see that in the code you provided. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph#userdata

Comment: thanks, passing permission with graph api as well as with login button is working.

Answer (score 0):

Since v2.4 you need include in your request the fields that you need.

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                     AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                          @Override
                          public void onCompleted(JSONObject userMe, GraphResponse response) {
                              if(userMe!=null){
                                 //...... do your things 

                              }
                          }
                }); 

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

//Add the fields that you need, you dont forget add the right permission
  parameters.putString("fields","email,id,name,picture,birthday");
  request.setParameters(parameters);

//Now you can execute
             GraphRequest.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code block that worked for me:

```java
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            final JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();
                            try{
                                email = jsonObject.getString("email");
                                first_name = jsonObject.getString("first_name");
                                last_name = jsonObject.getString("last_name");
                                gender = jsonObject.getString("gender");
                                birthday = jsonObject.getString("birthday");
                            } catch (JSONException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "email,first_name,last_name,gender,birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
```

Hope this helps!