# An unknown error has occurred on Graph Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to get Data from Facebook Page with the graph of Facebook but I have a problem.

When I try to go on link like:
https://graph.facebook.com/ID-PAGE?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN

I always do this to have the Data from a Page but since today I have the error Message: "An unknown error has occurred".

Thanks for help.

EDIT:

The bug is fixed : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/486654544831076/?search_id

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Some more info: I'm using php-sdk-v4, API version: 2.3. Another API call I make: /USER-ID/posts does actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer at

- [How to get user email and birthday from Facebook API Version v2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554854/how-to-get-user-email-and-birthday-from-facebook-api-version-v2-4/31556390#31556390)

You have to specify each field you want to query now with v2.4. If you want to explicitly use v2.3, you need to prepend your calls by `/v2.3` like this:

```
/v2.3/{page_id}?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Seems like there's currently a bug regarding requests made with app access tokens instead of user access tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/486654544831076/

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips with v2.4

Yes i know how to do with v2.3 but always say An unknown error has occurred

Comment: Try `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/cocacola?access_token={your_access_token}` This works flawlessly for me. If you receive an error, inspect your access token via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: Yes yesterday i have the same link and it work and today it don't work i don't think it's me

Comment: Until the probable bug is fixed... So what is the question you're having?

Comment: The question was if it's only me who have this bug, if i do nothing wrong in my link !

Comment: There are 22 subscribers of this bug, and several comments. So, do` you understand from this that it's not only you?

Comment: Yes i understand, I just need to change all the code of my application ><'

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, I pretty much figured out what is happening, and it looks like a bug in the Facebook API.

For v2.3 and lower:
The `/PAGE-ID` call will return an `Unknown server error` when you don't pass  `?fields=username` (for example). If you do pass the fields option, it will work. You can get it out of the docs.

For v2.4:
This will work, but you will miss a lot of data, so you'll also have to pass the fields options. But if you don't pass that, this version will give you back only the most basic of details. This is as described in the version release: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/07/08/graph-api-v2.4/

So the solution for now, would be to add the `?fields=` everywhere you need, or to wait for Facebook to maybe ever solve it.
(And while you're at it, you might as well upgrade to v2.4 ;-)

Comment: What you write is not correct. I can query `/v2.3/me` without `fields` and it's not returning an error at all. And where exactly is the documentation incomplete? The field list is to be found at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page#Reading Especially the the `username` field is a bad example, because it's deprecated!

Comment: It might be more specific for pages, can you try `/v2.3/349433361829726` without `fields`? The field list for the page page might be complete, but for https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed it isn't. Try getting the picture of a post, based on that documentation.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed#read says `An array of Post objects.

`, and the linked https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post clearly states that there is a `picture` field for each post returned by `page_id/feed`

Comment: Never mind, I read the wrong field parts of the docs. Let me change that. Thanks.

Comment: To be honest, I don't get it... Why doesn't it make sense? It's crystal clear IMHO. Use `/page_id?fields=feed{id,picture}`

Comment: That's not what I was implying :-) But, I'm with you that the docs are sometimes bad and/or hard to understand..

Comment: Thanks dude! Your answer helped a lot!

Comment: For me, I was using an expired `container id` for publish content endpoint.