# FACEBOOK SDK v4 is returning blank email adress

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm using facebook sdk v4 and i can't seem to get the EMAIL ADDRESS. Here is my code. I have searched each and every link on internet and tried every thing. Also tried different scripts but still i'm getting null email. Here is my code.

```
/* INCLUSION OF LIBRARY FILEs*/
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');

/* USE NAMESPACES */

    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\GraphUser;
    use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
    use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
    use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
    use Facebook\FacebookCurl;

/*PROCESS*/

    //1.Stat Session
     session_start();

    //check if users wants to logout
     if($_REQUEST['logout']==1){
        unset($_SESSION['fb_token']);
     }

    //2.Use app id,secret and redirect url 
    $app_id = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    $app_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $redirect_url='http://someurl.com/';

    //3.Initialize application, create helper object and get fb sess
     FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);
     $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
     $sess = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

    //check if facebook session exists
    if(isset($_SESSION['fb_token'])){
        $sess = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['fb_token']);
    }

    //logout
    $logout = 'http://dryvr.co/fb/?logout=1';

    //4. if fb sess exists echo name 
        if(isset($sess)){
            //store the token in the php session
            $_SESSION['fb_token']=$sess->getToken();
            //create request object,execute and capture response
            $request = new FacebookRequest($sess,'GET','/me');
            // from response get graph object
            $response = $request->execute();
            $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::classname());
            // use graph object methods to get user details
            $name = $graph->getName();
            $id = $graph->getId();
            $image = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/picture?width=300';
            $email = $graph->getProperty('email');
            echo "hi $name <br>";
            echo "your email is $email <br><Br>";
            echo "<img src='$image' /><br><br>";
            echo "<a href='".$logout."'><button>Logout</button></a>";
        }else{
            //else echo login
            echo '<a href="'.$helper->getLoginUrl(array('email')).'" >Login with facebook</a>';
        }
```

I have used `$email = $graph->getProperty('email');` but still I can not access the email address and it is returning blank email. What should I do? Thoughts?

Comment: You may want to remove the `$app_secret` bit.. sounds like something that should be a secret..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at my answer here:

- [How to get user email and birthday from Facebook API Version v2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554854/how-to-get-user-email-and-birthday-from-facebook-api-version-v2-4/31556390#31556390)

You need to specify each field you want returned from the Graph API starting with v2.4, e.g.

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($sess,'GET','/me?fields=id,name,email');
```

It's all in the Facebook docs.